# Adobe Omniture DTM

Tags: android, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have successfully implemented Omniture our Android App but we want the DTM to be incorporated.

I have checked for documentation but i am not able to find any.

This is where i have looked into :

http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/release/c_release_notes_android.html

Also i have implemented the DTM in my App, in the console i am able to see the logs but its not updating in the Dashboard,

What all changes that i need to make ?

Comment: Last I checked, DTM wasn't available for mobile apps. As for the lack of reporting, there could be 100 different things but check your data center and selecting one other than "auto". We recently had to manually set our to Dallas to work.

Comment: @BrettAHale Thanks, can you please elaborate on what you are trying to point out ?

Comment: In your Analytics Tool setup within DTM, not in a rule, under the general settings, there is a "Data Center" option. Try each one, not "auto" and see if that works.

Comment: @BrettAHale You mean in here https://sc2.omniture.com/login/ right ?

Comment: dtm.adobe.com in the tag manager setup. Maybe, I'm not getting what you're asking. You have implemented DTM (tag manager) on your web app, created a Analytics tool and you're seeing pixel calls correct? Or, are you just seeing the DTM library load?

Comment: Did u add DTM RSID in your code.

Comment: Check this link for chrome and firefox plugin http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/marketing-cloud-forum/adobe-marketing-cloud.topic.html/forum__lkzf-_dtm_switchdt.html

Answer (score 0):

Official "Getting Started" guide for Adobe DTM is here:
https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/dtm/get_started.html

You'll also want to get the DTM switch extension for Chrome [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-dtm-switch/nlgdemkdapolikbjimjajpmonpbpmipk?hl=en) and Firefox [here](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/marketing-cloud-forum/adobe-marketing-cloud.topic.19.html/forum__lkzf-_dtm_switchdt.html). It allows you to switch on the DTM debug console statements, as well as switch between staging and production versions of the DTM code.

Use the network tab of the browser's developer tools to inspect the tags and variables sent.